# How to Convert an int to a String?

Tags: java, string

I have an int variable and when I am setting this variable as an Android TextView's text it's throwing an error, maybe because it's an Int. I have checked but couldn't find a toString function for the int. So how can I do that?

```
int sdRate=5;
//text_Rate is a TextView
text_Rate.setText(sdRate); //gives error
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use [String.valueOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)):

```
int sdRate=5;
//text_Rate is a TextView
text_Rate.setText(String.valueOf(sdRate)); //no more errors
```

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between `String.valueOf` and `Integer.toString` ?

Comment: Why does (String) getMeasuredWidth() not work?

Comment: @M.Elsaka That is also my question, why does this work and not `toString()`?

Answer (score 13):

Use the `Integer` class' static [`toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) method.

```
int sdRate=5;
text_Rate.setText(Integer.toString(sdRate));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
text_Rate.setText(""+sdRate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
text_Rate.setText(String.valueOf(sdRate));
```

Comment: i *think* that since java has a mixed model concerning primitives and classes that you can't call any methods directly on an int. You must either use the Integer class' static toString() or cast it to an Integer first then call toString() on that.

Comment: Sorry the last one wouldnt work so i edited my answer. But, String.valueOf(sdRate) does work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Using [**String.valueOf()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method:

```
int sdRate=5;
text_Rate.setText(String.valueOf(sdRate));  //faster!, recommended! :)
```

2) adding an empty string:

```
int sdRate=5;
text_Rate.setText("" + sdRate));
```

Casting is not an option, will throw a `ClassCastException`

```
int sdRate=5;
text_Rate.setText(String.valueOf((String)sdRate)); //EXCEPTION!
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try like this

```
int sdRate=5;
//text_Rate is a TextView
text_Rate.setText(sdRate+""); //gives error
```