# Android:converting int to string and passing to methods

Tags: java, android

Hi I am using the android wheel and getting the values of the time as below

```
 //get values of the wheel
                   hourvalue = hours.getCurrentItem();
                   Log.d(TAG, "hour value" +hourvalue );

                   minutevalue = mins.getCurrentItem(); 
                   Log.d(TAG, "minute value" +minutevalue );
```

i want to pass them to a method as string , how can i do that and also  iam getting the values of hours and minutes separately i want to store the hours and minutes in a single string variable anAndroid :numberpicker in alert dailog

```
private String getTraceId(String fbuserser,int hour) {
        String traceId = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod get = null;
        try {

            get = new GetMethod("http://" + Constants.CLOUD_SERVER_URL
                    + Constants.facebookTrace);

                NameValuePair[] params = new NameValuePair[4];
            NameValuePair param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("gadget");
            param.setValue("gettraceid");

            params[0] = param;
            param = new NameValuePair();
                param.setName("fbuserid");
            param.setValue(fduserUser);
            params[1] = param;

            param = new NameValuePair();
            param.setName("expiry");
        ------------->  param.setValue(hour);
            params[2] = param;

            get.setQueryString(params);
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(get);
            traceId = get.getResponseBodyAsString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "For Facebook Trace Id:", e);

        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
            get = null;
        }
        return traceId;
```

In the above method i want to pass `int hour` as string.Any help is appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert an int to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841559/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* you're looking for something as simple as:

```
param.setValue(String.valueOf(hour));
```

There's also `Integer.toString(hour))`, but I like the fact that I can use `String.valueOf` with *all* types, without worrying about it :)

Comment: thankyou, is there any way ican pass both hour and minute in a single string?

Comment: @teekib: Sure - but you'd need to think about the format carefully. For example, do you want it to be a 2-digit minute value in all cases? (e.g. 1:00 instead of 1:0)?

Comment: well you can convert `hour` into minutes and add it to the `minute` variable, then pass only `minute`

Comment: i want twodigit...how convert hour into minutes and add it to the minute variable, then pass only minute???

Comment: @teekib: Well you can multiply by 60... if that's not useful enough for you, I suggest you ask a different question, as we're now quite a long way from what you originally asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your int into String.

```
String h = String.valueOf(hour);
```

Comment: @Mithesh   thankyou, is there any way ican pass both hour and minute in a single string?

Comment: yes possible.. Just concat with any symbol and at the destination just split it..

Comment: i didn't get you..can u explain

Comment: String original = hour +","+ minute;  String received[] = original.split(",")

Comment: sorry for too many question how can i pass that array in my params?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24558/discussion-between-mitesh-and-teekib)

Answer (score 0):

you can also concatenate:

```
String h = hour+"";
```